# Solr search results slow for latest created documents

Tags: performance, caching, solr

We have CMS which uses solr for indexing .Whenever we create any articles or modified anything it takes around 2 min to be available on solr search. But search result are very fast for older contents.

As a beginner in solr not sure what configuration might help us to improve the performance.Trying to provide some information here if anyone can suggests what i can do to improve search results.I see in filterCache section warmupTime is huge and it increases gradually.
There is no performance issue interms of CPU and memory,JVM etc. We have very good resource allocated to the master solr VM.

Solr details:

```
Solr Specification Version: 1.4.1
Solr Implementation Version: 1.4.1 955763M - mark - 2010-06-17 18:06:42
Lucene Specification Version: 2.9.3
```

CORE

```
name:   core  
class:  public  
version:    1.0  
description:    SolrCore  
stats:  coreName : public
startTime : Thu Nov 26 00:58:35 EST 2020
refCount : 3
aliases : [public]
name:   searcher  
class:  org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher  
version:    1.0  
description:    index searcher  
stats:  searcherName : Searcher@41eb6239 main
caching : true
numDocs : 4554313
maxDoc : 4581494
reader : SolrIndexReader{this=329487a5,r=ReadOnlyDirectoryReader@329487a5,refCnt=1,segments=22}
readerDir : org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory@/var/lib/polopoly/index/public/data/index
indexVersion : 1337271130654
openedAt : Fri Nov 27 18:15:51 EST 2020
registeredAt : Fri Nov 27 18:16:51 EST 2020
warmupTime : 60051
name:   Searcher@41eb6239 main  
class:  org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher  
version:    1.0  
description:    index searcher  
stats:  searcherName : Searcher@41eb6239 main
caching : true
numDocs : 4554313
maxDoc : 4581494
reader : SolrIndexReader{this=329487a5,r=ReadOnlyDirectoryReader@329487a5,refCnt=1,segments=22}
readerDir : org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory@/var/lib/polopoly/index/public/data/index
indexVersion : 1337271130654
openedAt : Fri Nov 27 18:15:51 EST 2020
registeredAt : Fri Nov 27 18:16:51 EST 2020
warmupTime : 60051
```

name:   queryResultCache

```
class:  org.apache.solr.search.LRUCache  
version:    1.0  
description:    LRU Cache(maxSize=512, initialSize=512, autowarmCount=32, regenerator=org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher$3@653cca0e)  
stats:  lookups : 0
hits : 0
hitratio : 0.00
inserts : 32
evictions : 0
size : 32
warmupTime : 128
cumulative_lookups : 9141
cumulative_hits : 6418
cumulative_hitratio : 0.70
cumulative_inserts : 2747
cumulative_evictions : 0
```

name:   documentCache

```
class:  org.apache.solr.search.LRUCache  
version:    1.0  
description:    LRU Cache(maxSize=512, initialSize=512)  
stats:  lookups : 0
hits : 0
hitratio : 0.00
inserts : 0
evictions : 0
size : 0
warmupTime : 0
cumulative_lookups : 478889
cumulative_hits : 413900
cumulative_hitratio : 0.86
cumulative_inserts : 64989
cumulative_evictions : 29649
```

name:   fieldValueCache

```
class:  org.apache.solr.search.FastLRUCache  
version:    1.0  
description:    Concurrent LRU Cache(maxSize=10000, initialSize=10, minSize=9000, acceptableSize=9500, cleanupThread=false)  
stats:  lookups : 0
hits : 0
hitratio : 0.00
inserts : 0
evictions : 0
size : 0
warmupTime : 0
cumulative_lookups : 0
cumulative_hits : 0
cumulative_hitratio : 0.00
cumulative_inserts : 0
cumulative_evictions : 0
```

name:   filterCache

```
class:  org.apache.solr.search.FastLRUCache  
version:    1.0  
description:    Concurrent LRU Cache(maxSize=512, initialSize=512, minSize=460, acceptableSize=486, cleanupThread=false, autowarmCount=128, regenerator=org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher$2@2a11890d)  
stats:  lookups : 0
hits : 0
hitratio : 0.00
inserts : 0
evictions : 0
size : 128
warmupTime : 59731
cumulative_lookups : 4325
cumulative_hits : 4179
cumulative_hitratio : 0.96
cumulative_inserts : 146
cumulative_evictions : 0
```

Newrelic report:

```
Category           Slowest components    Count     Duration      %
SolrRequestHandler  UpdateProcessor        1        63,600 ms   100%
```

Comment: Solr 1.4 is so old that it's hard to remember exactly which features were available, but this might be more down to your commit settings and how any queries are optimized; as well as whether you're replicating to a dedicated search server, etc. (which would also add a delay). Since the UpdateRequestHandler gets 63s as its runtime from NewRelic, it seems like you have requested to wait for the searcher to be opened. You can also tweak how many queries are used for auto warming with `autoWarmCount`, but that may have been introduced after 1.4.

Comment: Thanks .We have  one master solr server and multiple slave server for replication.But we are running the search query directly on master server.

Comment: should replication impacts for search results from master? We are not searching in slave server. I see there is autoWarmCount configuration. e.g.                                            <filterCache  class="solr.FastLRUCache" size="5120" initialSize="5120" autowarmCount="128"/>. 
Any tips adjusting this value? I see "warmupTime : 59731" for filterCache.

Comment: Depending on your query load you might not need any warming at all (or just a lower number of queries); you could at least test if it affects performance. Replication should not affect from master, but if you were searching on the slave server you'd have to wait for replication to happen as well. How are you committing the documents?

Comment: name:  filterCache  
class:  org.apache.solr.search.FastLRUCache  
version:  1.0  
description:  Concurrent LRU Cache(maxSize=5120, initialSize=5120, minSize=4608, acceptableSize=4864, cleanupThread=false, autowarmCount=128, regenerator=org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher$2@78db81f3)  
stats:  lookups : 0
hits : 0
hitratio : 0.00
inserts : 0
evictions : 0
size : 125
warmupTime : 68874
cumulative_lookups : 2450
cumulative_hits : 2321
cumulative_hitratio : 0.94
cumulative_inserts : 129
cumulative_evictions : 0

Comment: Above is the  details with warmupcount and hit  of filterCache which is only having huge warmuptime .I am not sure about hoe committing is happening in this legacy system.

Comment: With 128 in warmupcount and 129 cumulative inserts it seems like your whole set of filters applied is cached. My guess is that you can safely reduce it to just have the five or ten most used queries (if your filters are rather constant as it seems like), and spend a bit more time when those seldomly used queries arrive instead (since the cache won't be pre-warmed in that case). You can use a value like `50%` to only keep half of the cached filters, which will drift towards having the most efficient cache over time if you commit often.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for suggestion.We have lower the autowarmcount and see some improvement today.Currently we set it 32.